# If $\sum_{n \geq 1}X_n$ converges a.s. then $\forall a > 0: \sum P(|X_n|>a) < \infty$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I'd like to show that for $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ a sequence of real-valued and independent random variables,

> If $\sum_{n \geq 1}X_n$ converges a.s., then $\forall a > 0: \sum
>  P(|X_n|>a) < \infty$

I know that since $\sum X_n$ converges a.s. then it converges in probability.

For $A_n = \{|X_n| >a\}$ if $P(\limsup A_n) \neq 1 \Rightarrow \sum P(A_n) < \infty$ by Borel-Cantelli as the $A_n$ are independent. I thought I might be able to show that the event $\limsup A_n$ is not in the tail sigma algebra and so by Kolmogorov's 0-1 law the question would be answered, but I got stuck at this point.

Comment: The event $\limsup A_n$ _is_ a tail event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Borel-Cantelli lemma is a good idea. Assume that for some $a>0$, the series $\sum_n\mathbb P\{|X_n|>a\}$ is divergent. Using independence, we obtain that $\mathbb P\{\limsup_{n\to +\infty}A_n\}=1$. If $\omega\in\limsup_n A_n$, then the sequence $(X_n(\omega))_{n\geqslant 1}$ does not converge to $0$.

Actually, we only needed independence and the fact that $X_n\to 0$ a.s.

Comment: But how do I know that $X_n \rightarrow 0$ a.s.? Can one show this from the fact that the sum converges a.s.?

Comment: If a series of real numbers $\sum_na_n$ converges then $a_n\to 0$.